# What's the nicest way of mocking out collaborators when doing BDD in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mocking, bdd

I've been working with Objective C and Cocoa/iOS and testing like a mockist. ([Definition](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs))

- I want to mock out the collaborators of an object using OCMock.
- There are two ways of doing this in Objective C I'm aware of:

  1. Dependency Injection
  2. Setting internal state - either through Accessors or setValue:forKey:

**Which Should I Use?**

I don't like either of these. But I've got to use one... unless there's other options I'm not aware of.

**1. Dependency Injection**

This clutters my code, especially when the SUT has 2/3 collaborators. If the SUT needs to be passed 1/2 parameters, things start to look very messy indeed.

I understand that much beyond 3 there are too many dependencies and the object should be split up into other parts... but even with 2 dependencies and 1 parameter, it's still ugly as sin.

**2. Setting Internal State**

This messes with the internals of a class - which I thought was a big no-no in testing.

Accessors are definitely out - they expose data that no-one should know about.
I can use setValue:forKey: ... but this feels like a horrible hack.

It also means I have to init the SUT then swap out the real collaborators for mock ones, then run the method under test, which feels messy.

**My Question**

What's the nicest way to mock out collaborators in Objective C when doing BDD?

**Code**

**Mocking using setValue:forKey:**

```
@interface JGCompositeCommand : JGCommand <JGCompositeCommandProtocol> {
    NSMutableArray *commands;
    JGCommandFinderFactory *commandFinderFactory;
}

-(id <JGCommandProtocol>)initWithName:(NSString *)name_ recoverer:(id <JGCommandRecoveryProtocol>)recoverer_ executor:(id <JGCommandExecutorProtocol>)executor_;

@end

@implementation JGCompositeCommand

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name_ recoverer:(id)recoverer_ {
    self = [super initWithName:name_ recoverer:recoverer_];
    if (self) {
      commands = [NSMutableArray array];
      commandFinderFactory = [[JGCommandFinderFactory alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id <JGCommandProtocol>)commandWithName:(NSString *)name_ {
    return [[commandFinderFactory commandFinderWithCommandName:name_ andCommands:commands] findCommandWithName];
}

@end

@interface JGCommandTestCase : SenTestCase {
    JGCompositeCommand *compositeCommand;
    OCMockObject *commandFinderFactoryMock;
}

@end 

@implementation JGCommandTestCase

-(void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    compositeCommand = [[JGCompositeCommand alloc] initWithName:@"" recoverer:nil];
    commandFinderFactoryMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[JGCommandFinderFactory class]];
    // Hack alert! Ugh.
    [compositeCommand setValue:commandFinderFactoryMock forKey:@"commandFinderFactory"];
}

-(void)testGivenCommandNotFoundShouldThrow {
    // ** Setup **
    [[[commandFinderFactoryMock expect] andReturn:...] commandFinderWithCommandName:... andCommands:...];

    // ** Execute **
    [compositeCommand commandWithName:@"Blah"];

    // ** Asserts **
    [commandFinderFactoryMock verify];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach we've landed on is to make the collaborators singletons, and provide a way to inject a mock instance at test time:

```
static JGCommandFinder *sharedFinder = nil;

+(JGCommandFinder *)sharedFinder {
    if (sharedFinder == nil) sharedFinder = [[JGCommandFinder alloc] init];
    return sharedFinder;
}

+(void)setSharedFinder:(JGCommandFinder *)instance {
    sharedFinder = instance;
}
```

It's very flexible, as you can use the actual object, inject a mock even if the real one has been initialized, and reset it to use the real object by setting the instance to nil.

Comment: I'm confused - surely that would mean every single collaborator would be a singleton? And that surely means that most classes become singletons. And I thought a singleton was an anti-pattern.

Comment: I guess that depends what you mean by "every single collaborator". There are certainly other patterns for obtaining and configuring objects. The one you choose depends on your needs. For example, nibs are a form of dependency injection, so anything configured in a nib can be injected at test time. As to singleton as an anti-pattern, I think the primary criticism is that they're difficult to test as collaborators, which this approach seeks to resolve. Take a look at http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/2011/02/on-singletons/.